# why pyautogui hotkey does not function on mac

Tags: macos, pyautogui

I tried `pyautogui` on mac terminal with this simple function

```
def press_star():
    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.keyDown('8')
    pyautogui.keyUp('8')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

It will simply output "8" on Mac. I tried the same thing on windows, it works.
So is there anyway to make pyautogui works on Mac?

Comment: I am running MacOS Mojave (10.14) and it outputted me an asterisk, not an 8. Tried on both python 2.7 and 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyDown does work most of the time. However, sometimes it appears that the order of the "shift" and "8" key are off.

Running 20 times on MacOS Mojave (10.14) python 3.7 produced

```
****88**8*******8***
```

Also,

```
pyautogui.hotkey("shift", "8")
```

does the same thing, but is much quicker.